# Multiple Tabs in the same browser and IIS Concurrent Connection

Tags: iis, browser, tabs

I understand multiple tabs in a single browser shares the same session. But does it uses the same concurrent connection?

More specifically does each tab in the browser to the same website will create multiple concurrent connections or share a common connection.

I will be using IIS as my webserver.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many dynamics to this, and it depends on how you configure your WEBSITE, and the App Pool. For a standard website created with IIS and very little to no changes in the configuration, a single user (Browser) will issue a single connection from which multiple requests will take place. Of course, a single request will block until "completion".

However that being said, Browsers more or less have a "concurrent limit". Used to be set @ 2, but has now changed based on which one you use. Think Chrome is currently at 4.

Thirdly, browsers are a little smarter these days, and upon grabbing a page, they will open multiple requests (through a single connection - if HTTP Keep Alive set on IIS [default]) which will get images (resources) and the HTML concurrently.

HTH